# iOS -- configuring a UITableViewCell after the cell learns its size

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

Suppose I am creating a UITableViewCell subclass.  The cell will not know what its size is going to be until the controller tells it.

What is the proper way to organize configuration of the subviews?  They will want to determine their frames based on the size of the cell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create and setup subviews in cell's init method (if you're not using nib) and set their frames in cell's `-layoutSubviews` method - cell's size must be already defined when that method gets called

Comment: works great.  If anyone else does this, remember to call super in layoutSubviews.